# How to delete messages from .maildir/new/ with custom subject?

Tags: regex, linux, email, postfix-mta, maildir

I have new messages in my .maildir/new/. There are a lot of bug reports I would like to remove.

I would like to remove messages with subject that contains *Webkit*. How can I do it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each email is simply a file. Removing the file deletes the email.

```
grep -l -r Webkit .maildir/new | xargs rm
```